# How to integrate $\int x^2\sin^2(\frac{1}{x})\,\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

So I've been trying to do this integral for an hour and now I'm really stuck. Can anyone help?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed what you tried.

Comment: Try a variable substitution: u = 1/x

Comment: the result containes one nonelementary function

Comment: Have you evaluated the integral using software yet, e.g. Wolfram Alpha, to figure out what you're trying to work towards?

Comment: The integral cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: I've tried a substitution of u=1/x and it didn't work. All i got was dx=-dt*x^2.

Comment: @DavidMathers What we're saying is that it is not possible to do this integral completely. Maybe if you had limits for integration, but not like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=1/u$ to get

$$I=-\int\frac{\sin^2(u)}{u^4}~\mathrm du=\frac1{6u^3}+\int\frac{\cos(2u)}{2u^4}~\mathrm du$$

Integrate by parts to get

$$\begin{align}2I-\frac1{3u^3}&=-\frac{\cos(2u)}{3u^3}-\int\frac{2\sin(2u)}{3u^3}~\mathrm du\\
&=-\frac{\cos(2u)}{3u^3}+\frac{\sin(2u)}{3u^2}-\int\frac{2\cos(2u)}{3u^2}~\mathrm du\\&=-\frac{\cos(2u)}{3u^3}+\frac{\sin(2u)}{3u^2}+\frac{2\cos(2u)}{3u}+\int\frac{4\sin(2u)}{3u}~\mathrm du\\
&=-\frac{\cos(2u)}{3u^3}+\frac{\sin(2u)}{3u^2}+\frac{2\cos(2u)}{3u}+\frac43\operatorname{Si}(2u)+c\\
&=-\frac{x^3\cos(2/x)}{3}+\frac{x^2\sin(2/x)}{3}+\frac{2x\cos(2/x)}{3}+\frac43\operatorname{Si}(2/x)+c\end{align}$$

where $\operatorname{Si}(x)$ is the [sine integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral).

Comment: I think the sine should be squared.

Comment: Should be fixed now :-P  Thanks for the catch.